# Swift - Group variables/properties using extension

Tags: swift, grouping

Assumming I have a struct like this

```
struct MyStruct {
  var a1: Int // This property is for feature A
  var a2: Int // This property is for feature A
  var a3: Int // This property is for feature A
  var b1: Int // This property is for feature B
  var b2: Int // This property is for feature B
}
```

I want to know if there are any technique to create an extension for `MyStruct` so that I can have **a1, a2, a3** into a group (namely `aFeatures`), and **b1, b2** into another group (`bFeatures`) without changing the original implementation of `MyStruct` so that I can access the properties like this:

```
let obj = MyStruct()
let a1 = obj.aFeatures.a1 
let b1 = obj.bFeatures.b1
```

Thanks in advance!

**Back story**: MyStruct is a common data model that is used across my app; however for each feature/module (A or B) I only need to use some certain properties related to that feature therefore I want to group the properties to make the logic clearer.

Comment: Why not different structs, a protocol based solution or a type-erased wrapper?

Comment: This is legacy code that has existed for a long time, and we just want a simple solution for my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create **computed properties** `aFeatures` of type `(Int,Int,Int)`  and `bFeatures` of type `(Int,Int)`

```
extension MyStruct {
    var aFeatures: (a1: Int, a2: Int, a3: Int) {
        return (a1, a2, a3)
    }

    var bFeatures: (b1: Int, b2: Int) {
        return (b1, b2)
    }
}
```

Then, you can access relevant values from `aFeatures` and `bFeatures`

```
let obj = MyStruct()
let a1 = obj.aFeatures.a1
let b1 = obj.bFeatures.b1
```